# ImportError: No module named dtracedata

Tags: python-2.7

I m using this line in my python code

```
from test.dtracedata import instances
```

in eclipse.

Python Version-2.7.15

Then it will show this error

> importerror: no module named dtracedata

Comment: Have you verified you have `__init__.py` in `test`?

Comment: No.How can i do it?

Comment: Just create an empty file named `__init__.py` so the interpreter will know to treat your directory as a package.